# Adding new animation to current animator

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, animator

I drag the new animation (Bigger) on the current animator. The problem comes when I click on Bigger, then I Click my player for adding properties and automatically changes to Idle Animation, so I can't add properties to Bigger and configure it.

I'm trying to configure the Bigger state.

What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: click on _Player_, and around the top left of the _Animation_ window, there's a drop-down to select the _animation_.

Comment: Click on the object holding the Animator, than you can change the animation in the `Animation` window as JTizzle says. It might help in some cases to lock the window (the little lock symbol on the top right of every window tab)

Comment: I've updated with a new photo, as you can see I can't click anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Click on the object holding the Animator, than you can change the animation in the `Animation` window,  around the top left there's a drop-down to select the animation.